# extending superclass and ClassCastException

Tags: java, casting, overriding, classcastexception, superclass

I have a superclass, which two methods i want to override. Here's my code:

```
public class MyCustomClass extends SomeSuperClass {

protected MyCustomClass(params) {
    super(params);
}
@Override
public void method1() {
    super.method1();
    /* here goes my code */
}
@Override
public void method2() {
    super.method2();
    /* here goes my another code  */
}
```

I have some constructor, that passes SomeSuperClass object as a parameter, and what i do next:

```
MyCustomClass object;
/* now i have object of type SomeSuperClass,
but with my own method1() and method2() */
object = (MyCustomClass) MyCustomClass.item(blahblah); 
/* eclipse suggests casting, because MyCustomClass.item()
 constructor still returns SomeSuperClass object */
otherobject = OtherConstructor.object(object);
//OtherConstructor passes SomeSuperClass object
```

That seems to be right, but i'm getting java.lang.ClassCastException in SomeSuperClass while executing.

if i create SomeSuperClassObject, i lose my overriden methods.

With casting, even if there's no errors in eclipse, application crashes. 
In other words, how i can override SomeSuperClass with my own methods, and still get SomeSuperClass object to use with OtherConstructor?
If it is important, this code is for android app.

Comment: What's the code for `MyCustomClass.item` ?

Comment: it's not overriden, so it is (and it really is, according to eclipse code assistant) just use superclass method

Comment: to be pedantic, `MyCustomClass.item()` is not a "constructor" nor is `OtherConstructor.object()`

Answer (score 17):

As a general rule, you can cast an instance of a subclass to its parent class:

```
MyCustomClass object = new MyCustomClass(params);
SomeSuperClass superClass = (SomeSuperClass) object;
```

However, you cannot cast an instance of a superclass to a subclass:

```
SomeSuperClass object = new SomeSuperClass(params);
MyCustomClass customClass = (MyCustomClass) object; // throws ClassCastException
```

This is because a `MyCustomClass` object is also a `SomeSuperClass` object, but not all `SomeSuperClass` objects are `MyCustomClass` objects.

You may be able to work around this with certain design patterns.  Java itself tends to use the [Decorator pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern) a lot.

Comment: I'm always forgetting which direction is OK. This helps.

Answer (score 0):

If the `item()` method is declared in `SomeSuperClass`, I doubt that it is returning an instance of `MyCustomClass`.  So your cast `(MyCustomClass) MyCustomClass.item(blahblah)` would be invalid.

Comment: why not? if he has both botch classes at compile time, the static method item() in parent can return the specific subclass instance (like some sort of simple factory method)...

Comment: Yes, you're right that it could be written that way; but I rather doubt it.  I'll rephrase.

Answer (score 0):

From what I see it seems that MyCustomClass.item(blahblah) call returns something different (maybe the parent) than MyCustomClass. Its the only part in te code, where you are casting object...

Comment: so thats your problem, you cannot cast parent instance to the child. Inheritence construct can be translated to IS language construct. In your case, you have a Mammal (superclass) and Human (subclass) and Rabbit subclass. You can create Human h and say "h IS a mammal (Mammal m = new Human())", but you cannot say that every Mammal is Human (Mammal m = new Rabit; Human h = (Human) m)...and thats what you have done, and why you have the classcastexception...

Comment: as I look at it, you did slightly different mistake...you said, that Human h = new Mammal(), but thats not true, because abstract mammal (your superclass) has 4 legs, and human has 2 hands and 2 legs...so you cant cast reference to the parent to the child....you can do this only if the parent reference contains the child object (Mammal m = new Human(); Human h = (Human) m) - by this you say, this human is a mammal - this concrete mammal (wont work for every mammal) is a human.

Answer (score 0):

looks like problem solved. I tried

```
object = new MyCustomClass(blahblah);
```

and it worked.
BTW, can somebody explain that?

Comment: I know this is very old but it might still prove helpful for people looking for answer. Of course, that would work because it's the standard way of creating objects via constructor methods. As a reference, like mentioned before, you can create child class objects pointed by parent class variables. So the original object was always a child object but is now referenced as a parent variable. This can be downcasted back to be pointed by a child variable anytime.