# Android Studio: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout, canvas

I am a beginner and I am doing an Android game which I made the model in Java (on Eclipse).

I'm actually trying to draw a grid, but when I run, I have a `java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity`

I don't really understand where the problem is, it says the problem is from the `setContentView (R.layout.activity_main)`.

This is my AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="e.khoig.test2">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        tools:ignore="GoogleAppIndexingWarning">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

This is where it contains the game and its creation:

```
public class Game extends Application {
    TenGame tenGame;

    public void onCreate(){
        super.onCreate();
        tenGame=new TenGame();

    }

    TenGame getTenGame(){
        return tenGame;
    }
}
```

Then this is my GameView which I draw and do the actions:

```
public class GameView extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback{
    Game gam;
    Paint paint=new Paint();
    int canvasWidth;
    int cellSize;

    public GameView(Context context, AttributeSet attributeSet){
        super(context,attributeSet);
        getHolder().addCallback(this);
        getGam(context);
    }

    public GameView(Context context){
        super(context);
        getHolder().addCallback(this);
        this.getGam(context);
    }

    public final void getGam(Context context){
        gam=(Game)(context.getApplicationContext());
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {

    }


    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) {
        canvasWidth=width;
        cellSize=width/5;
        reDraw();
    }


    public void reDraw(){
        Canvas c=getHolder().lockCanvas();
        if(c!=null){
            this.onDraw(c);
            getHolder().unlockCanvasAndPost(c);

        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        int x=(int)event.getX();
        int y=(int)event.getY();

        int action=event.getAction();
        TenGame theGame=gam.getTenGame();
        switch(action){
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:{
                theGame.getSelectedGroup();
            }
            default:
                return false;
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {

    }
    @Override
    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas){
        paint.reset();
        TenGame theGame=gam.getTenGame();
        canvas.drawColor(Color.GRAY);

        paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        for(int x=0;x<canvasWidth;x+=cellSize){
            canvas.drawLine(x,0,x,canvasWidth,paint);
        }
        for(int y=0;y<canvasWidth;y+=cellSize){
            canvas.drawLine(0,y,canvasWidth,y,paint);
        }

        paint.setTextSize(50);
        paint.setFlags(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);

        for(int x=0;x<5;x++){
            for(int y=0;y<5;y++){
                canvas.drawText("1",(x*cellSize)+11,(cellSize+y*cellSize)-6,paint);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And finally my MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    Game gam;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        gam=(Game)this.getApplication();

    }
}
```

And my activity_main.xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World!"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <e.khoig.test2.GameView
        android:id="@+id/gameView"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
         />

</LinearLayout>
```

This is my error message:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: e.khoig.test2, PID: 15920
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{e.khoig.test2/e.khoig.test2.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #18: Binary XML file line #18: Error inflating class e.khoig.test2.GameView
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2957)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3032)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1696)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6944)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:327)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1374)
 Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #18: Binary XML file line #18: Error inflating class e.khoig.test2.GameView
 Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #18: Error inflating class e.khoig.test2.GameView
 Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:334)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:647)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:790)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:730)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:863)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:824)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374)
    at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:461)
    at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2737)
    at e.khoig.test2.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:12)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7183)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1220)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2910)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3032)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1696)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6944)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:327)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1374)
 Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.app.Application cannot be cast to e.khoig.test2.Game
    at e.khoig.test2.GameView.getGam(GameView.java:34)
    at e.khoig.test2.GameView.<init>(GameView.java:24)
```

UPDATE : 
I resolved my problem, i just had to declare the application in the manifest, thank you for your helps !

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please don't tag questions with the android-studio tag just because you use it: the Android Studio tag should **only** be used when you have questions about the IDE itself, and not any code you write (or want to write) in it. See [when is it appropriate to remove an IDE tag](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/315196/6296561), [How do I avoid misusing tags?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/354427/how-do-i-avoid-misusing-tags), and [the tagging guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging)

Answer (score 0):

The 3rd last line in your **stacktrace** states that you can't cast **application** to an instance of your **game** class.

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.app.Application cannot be cast to e.khoig.test2.Game
```

In your **main activity** after **setContentView** could you use **getActivity** without the **this** i.e.

```
gam = (Game) getActivity();
```

I believe the problem right now could be that you are trying to cast an instance of **application** to an instance of **activity**.

Just my two cents.

Comment: I can't do the getActivity().

Answer (score 0):

The stack trace says -

`Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.app.Application cannot be cast to e.khoig.test2.Game
    at e.khoig.test2.GameView.getGam(GameView.java:34)`

You are doing this -

`public final void getGam(Context context){
        gam=(Game)(context.getApplicationContext());
 }`

You should not cast the instance of superclass to subclass. This is leading to your `ClassCastException`.

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4260950/8882173) gives a better picture.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Hello, thank you for your help, then what should i do the get the application ?

Answer (score 0):

This stack trace shows this

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.app.Application cannot be cast to e.khoig.test2.Game
```

Because this

```
A extends B
A a = new B()  // this is wrong
(B)a//this is wrong
B b = new A()  // this is right
(A)b // this is right
```

You cannot  cast the instance of superclass to subclass.